# Process functions from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, function, exec

I have a module that I import to my main application called pageprocs.py with a collection of functions in it that generate different content and return it in a string. pageprocs is supposed to be a way of allowing authenticated users to create plugins for the different content type.

I then have a list of strings: ['check_stats', 'build_table', 'build_ace'] which are the names of some functions in pageprocs. I need to execute the functions in the order they are in the list and can't find a way of doing this without using exec():

```
for i in list_of_funcs:
    exec('pageprocs.%s()' % i)
```

This just seems like a seriously bad idea to me and not easy to catch any exceptions in users code. Is there an alternative to running code this way or does anybody have suggestions on user-defined content generation (I ask this because I maybe approaching the whole situation wrong).

Comment: where do you get `list_of_funcs`? Why don't you store functions in it directly?

Comment: list_of_funcs is created by reading variables placed in a template file so users are aware of the areas of the template that need content. The template file is read as a string during content creation so the function names are also stored as a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for i in list_of_stats:
    getattr(pageprocs, i, lambda: None)()
```

The `lambda: None` part is optional, but will prevent `AttributeError` being raised if the specified function doesn't exist (it's an anonymous do-nothing function).

Comment: Wish I had the reputation to mod this up. Very clean and it works.

Comment: +1 Although as a matter of personal style I don't like the null callable and would prefer `if hasattr(pageprocs, i): getattr(pageprocs, i)()` or even `func = getattr(pageprocs, i); if callable(func): func()`

Comment: At first I thought you meant `TypeError`, which is what you would expect to get if you try to call `None()`, but if `i` is simply not part of `pageprocs` you would get an `AttributeError`, not a `NameError`. Unless I misunderstood…